# Xcode linker error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c++, xcode, linker-errors

Using C++ and Xcode I always run into this problem where linker command fails. I don't know what this means. I'm creating an elementary program that consists of 3 files. A main.cpp, and a class file that has a header. The main file is empty. This what the other two look like:

**student.hpp :**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>

std::string line;
class Student{
public:
    std::string fullName;
    int projectGrade;
    int quizGrade;
    int midtermGrade;
    int finalGrade;
    int finish;
    int start = 14;

    std::string getStudentName();
    int getProjectGrade();
    int getQuizGrade();
    int getMidtermGrade();
    int getFinalGrade();
    double getOverallGrade();
    bool login(std::string username, std::string password);
    bool login(std::string username);
};
```

**student.cpp**:

```
#include "student.hpp"

std::string Student::getStudentName(){
    finish = line.find("\t", start);
    fullName = line.substr(start, finish);
    return fullName;
}
int Student::getProjectGrade(){
    start = line.find("\t", start) + finish;
    finish = start + 2;
    std::stringstream stream(line.substr(start, 2));
    stream >> projectGrade;
    return projectGrade;
}
int Student::getQuizGrade(){
    start+=3;
    std::stringstream stream(line.substr(start, 2));
    stream >> quizGrade;
    return quizGrade;
}
int Student::getMidtermGrade(){
    start+=3;
    std::stringstream stream(line.substr(start, 2));
    stream >> midtermGrade;
    return midtermGrade;
}
int Student::getFinalGrade(){
    start+=3;
    std::stringstream stream(line.substr(start, 2));
    stream >> finalGrade;
    return finalGrade;
}
double Student::getOverallGrade(){
    return round((projectGrade + quizGrade + midtermGrade + finalGrade)/40)*10;
}
bool Student::login(std::string username, std::string password){
    std::ifstream studentFile;
    studentFile.open("/Users/griffin/desktop/Data Structures/Data Structures1/Data Structures1/Students.txt");
    if(studentFile.is_open()){
        while(getline (studentFile,line))
        {
            if ((username.length() == 7 && username.substr(0,4).compare("u000") == 0 && line.find(username) != std::string::npos) && (password.length() == 6 && password.substr(0,2).compare("pw") == 0 && line.find(password) != std::string::npos))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
bool Student::login(std::string username){

    std::ifstream studentFile;
    studentFile.open("/Users/griffin/desktop/Data Structures/Data Structures1/Data Structures1/Students.txt");
    if(studentFile.is_open()){
        while(getline (studentFile,line))
        {
            if (username.length() == 7 && username.substr(0,4).compare("u000") == 0 && line.find(username) != std::string::npos)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The main file includes student.hpp. Is this a problem on Xcode's end or do I have an error in my code?

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "student.hpp"    
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The main file should include student.hpp, not student.cpp. Was that a typo? Could you post the complete error message?

Comment: And also having main.cpp including student.cpp will induce multiple definition errors. All standard duplicates.

Comment: Spiller that was a typo, I've updated my code to include the main function

Comment: @Griffin, now how about the error message?

Comment: "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: @Griffin Somewhere there should be more detail, it should tell you **why** it's failed. I don't know Xcode so I couldn't tell you how to find that out.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you've multiply declared the global variable `line`.

There is no good reason for a global variable in your code so the simple solution is to declare `line` inside the two login methods instead.

For future reference however, here's how you should declare global variables

[How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files/1433387#1433387)

Comment: std::string line; is only declared once in student.hpp, even though I use the line variable in student.cpp as well

Comment: @Griffen, but student.hpp is included **twice**, in student.cpp and main.cpp, so `line` gets declared twice resulting in a linker error. See my link for how to do global variables properly.